# How can you update same file in different directories using chef recipe

Tags: file, synchronization, chef-infra, cookbook

I have three folders on a chef node(dir1, dir2, dir3). Under this directory I have a common file secret.txt in all the directories, is there any way i can make sure if file edited in one directory is updated in other two directories.
Lets say i'm editing secret.txt in dir1, if i run the cookbook, secret.txt should be updated in dir2 and dir3, similarly if i update secret.txt in dir2 and run the chef cookbook, secret.txt should be updated in other two directories(dir1 and dir3). Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, you could write some very complex code that compared the modification time of the three files and all that, but seriously don't. Just have Chef be the thing that manages the content, not a human. Then it's as easy as three `file` resources.